# multiple JSON objects in fromJSON

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I'm trying to use `fromJSON()` to read in a .json file with multiple objects structured as follows:

```
{ "key11": value11, "key12": value12 }
{ "key11": value11, "key12": value12 }
…
```

If I manually add `[...]` brackets around the entire file, and `,` commas between the objects, then the following code works:

```
json_file <- "file.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(json_file,flatten=TRUE)
```

But adding the brackets and commas is not feasible for what I'm actually trying to do (I did it on a  sample file).

I tried using `readLines()` since the objects have newlines between them, but I didn't get anywhere.

How can I read in these json objects without modifying the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you know it's one per line, and no weird line breaks,

```
 lapply(readLines(filename), fromJSON, flatten = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you read references: the option `unexpected.escape` is available.

> **unexpected.escape**
>   changed handling of unexpected escaped characters. Handling value should be one of "error", "skip", or "keep"; on unexpected characters issue an error, skip the character, or keep the character