# multiple JSON objects into R from one txt file

Tags: json, r, twitter

I am very new to Json files. I scraped a txt file with some million json objects such as:

```json
{
    "created_at":"Mon Oct 14 21:04:25 +0000 2013",
    "default_profile":true,
    "default_profile_image":true,
    "description":"...",
    "followers_count":5,
    "friends_count":560,
    "geo_enabled":true,
    "id":1961287134,
    "lang":"de",
    "name":"Peter Schmitz",
    "profile_background_color":"C0DEED",
    "profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes", 
    "utc_offset":-28800,
    ...
}
{
    "created_at":"Fri Oct 17 20:04:25 +0000 2015",
    ...
}
```

I want to extract the columns into a data frame in R:

```
Variable          Value
created_at          X     
default_profile     Y     

 …
```

In general, similar to how done here([multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python)) in Python. If anyone has an idea or a suggestion, help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Here's possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023972/multiple-json-objects-in-fromjson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how you could approach it with two objects. I assume you were able to read the JSON from a file, otherwise see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r).

```
myjson = '{"created_at": "Mon Oct 14 21:04:25 +0000 2013", "default_profile": true, 
  "default_profile_image": true, "description": "...", "followers_count": 
    5, "friends_count": 560, "geo_enabled": true, "id": 1961287134, "lang":  
    "de", "name": "Peter Schmitz", "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",  
  "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes", "utc_offset": -28800}
{"created_at": "Mon Oct 15 21:04:25 +0000 2013", "default_profile": true, 
  "default_profile_image": true, "description": "...", "followers_count": 
    5, "friends_count": 560, "geo_enabled": true, "id": 1961287134, "lang":  
    "de", "name": "Peter Schmitz", "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",  
  "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes", "utc_offset": -28800}
'

library("rjson")

# Split the text into a list of all JSON objects. I chose '!x!x!' pretty randomly.. There may be better ways of keeping the brackets wile splitting.
my_json_objects = head(strsplit(gsub('\\}','\\}!x!x!', myjson),'!x!x!')[[1]],-1)
# read the text as JSON objects 
json_data <- lapply(my_json_objects, function(x) {fromJSON(x)})
# Transform to dataframes
json_data <- lapply(json_data, function(x) {data.frame(val=unlist(x))})
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
                                                            val
created_at                       Mon Oct 14 21:04:25 +0000 2013
default_profile                                            TRUE
default_profile_image                                      TRUE
description                                                 ...
followers_count                                               5
friends_count                                               560
geo_enabled                                                TRUE
id                                                   1961287134
lang                                                         de
name                                              Peter Schmitz
profile_background_color                                 C0DEED
profile_background_image_url http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes
utc_offset                                               -28800

[[2]]
                                                            val
created_at                       Mon Oct 15 21:04:25 +0000 2013
default_profile                                            TRUE
default_profile_image                                      TRUE
description                                                 ...
followers_count                                               5
friends_count                                               560
geo_enabled                                                TRUE
id                                                   1961287134
lang                                                         de
name                                              Peter Schmitz
profile_background_color                                 C0DEED
profile_background_image_url http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes
utc_offset                                               -28800
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP is *specifically* asking about files with multiple JSON objects in them (i.e. invalid JSON files).

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for the feedback. I am kind of new to JSON so I was not aware that that was the issue. I have updated my answer, do you think this better answers OP's question?

Comment: Thanks a lot, working perfectly! Just to add what might be helpful: If you wanna use this as a full table, use `json_data <-  lapply(json_data,t);
df <- plyr::ldply(json_data, rbind)`

Comment: @TSpinde I think you can even skip the transpose step if you replace the last line of my code with `json_data <- lapply(json_data, function(x) {data.frame(x)})`. Anyway, glad I could help and nice that you were able to make the modifications to make it work for you!